# Can one still buy a new, top-of-the-range film camera?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, film

Just wondering: can you still buy a new, top of the range camera that will produce a negative or a slide after you have taken a picture? Or have digital cameras taken over the market completely?

I know certain photography shops still deal with slides and negatives but they are slowly being phased out, sadly.

Despite having to contend with endless problems that come with owning a slide or negative — such as dust, dirt, fingerprints and scratches, there's nothing quite like a good slide or negative to treasure and cherish.

Comment: have you even tried to google that?

Comment: No and I have no intention of doing so. This is the problem with the younger generation today. No-one bothers to communicate with anyone. Technology does not always change for the better.

Comment: this website is not design to "communicate with anyone" but to get answer to questions, within scope and appropriate style. Googling or research if an important part of asking good questions: https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm not of the "younger generation" so please leave your prejudices at the door.  If you want a discussion type forum then try e.g. dpreview.com.

Comment: I think this is not so much a question as a semi-concealed digital-vs-film rant. Also, it is (to put it bluntly) ignorant to think that answers should not be researched first. You think it's better not to have an archive of information, but rather ask everything over and over again, in the name of "communication"?

Comment: @RichardGray 'No and I have no intention of doing so'...then I think the stackexchange platform is not the appropriate place for your personal rant.

Comment: @Stephen G - Never said you were.

It seems that some here cannot even answer basic questions, yet are able to moan and complain all day long because a question is apparently 'off-topic'. Really says a lot.

Comment: @RichardGray this really isn't a platform for personal rants, neither is it a platform for questions that are easily answerable by going to a shop (online or otherwise) to see a range of products. What Stephen is saying is that the nature of the question isn't really a fit for this site, and may be better asked on photography discussion forums, and that your attacking attitude does not belong here either. Leave that at the door, ask suitable questions that are a good fit for the site, and people will be happy to help and will upvote your questions instead of downvote them

Comment: Define a 'suitable' question worthy of respect and attention. I'm all ears.

Comment: There's no need for facetious comments either. Take a look at the 'Asking' section of help: https://photo.stackexchange.com/help, primarily the first two in that section: 'What topics can I ask about here?' and 'What types of questions should I avoid asking?'

Comment: Looking at the list in the help section, I would say my question falls into the 'photography' and 'photography in society' category. Of course it's still very subjective and there is still no clear definition.

Answer (score 7):

There are many film cameras being made and sold today.

For example for 35mm Nikon still makes the [F6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikon_F6) and sells the [FM10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikon_FM10) (manufactured by Cosina).

Leica still makes various film cameras for their [M mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leica_M-mount), like the [M-P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leica_MP) and M-A.

Medium and large format cameras are still made as well. For example Arca Swiss, Chamonix, Shen-Hao make new large format cameras.

Comment: Damn - beat me to it by a minute >_<

Answer (score 7):

There are still plenty of people shooting film. But, demand has indeed fallen, and it's become a buyer's market.

To my knowledge, only Nikon and Leica are making new 35mm gear - though I could be wrong. The real value is in used gear in great condition - and there's a lot to go around.

Canon's flagship EOS 1V can be had in mint condition for less than $500. Yea, it's some old tech compared to what's in the new digital cameras - but it's a beast of a camera.

For medium format, Pentax 645N's and lenses go for super cheap. A mint body with 75mm manual focus lens can be had for ~$600. The manual focus 35mm goes for ~$350 while a used copy of the autofocus 200mm can be had for $800 off retail. It's out of my budget but I've come across the 600mm f/5.6 for only $2,000. (Yea, it is expensive, but cheap compared to what Canon wants for a 600mm)

For most people, I don't think it makes sense to drop thousands on new film equipment - especially when there is top shelf gear to be had for so cheap.

Answer (score 1):

It's really too bad you didn't feel the need to [google that question](https://www.google.com/search?q=Can%20one%20still%20buy%20a%20new%2C%20top-of-the-range%20film%20camera&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS753US753&oq=Can%20one%20still%20buy%20a%20new%2C%20top-of-the-range%20film%20camera&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i64.854j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Because hit one would have been a great answer! "15 Film Cameras you can still buy brand new".

Now, this is the top google hit (Because the Exchange network is awesome for searching and finding answers as a Q&A site)

Additionally, cameras don't really take "slides or negatives", film cameras expose film, and then a lab converts the exposed film to slides, negatives, or digital (Often throwing away the negatives today)

And lastly film is making a comeback! At least for now. A generation has never really seen analog photography and are apparently fascinated with the process of it.

And we really shouldn't approach problems with the "kids these days" trope. Today's kids have inherited an unprecedentedly peaceful world, with access to incomprehensible data and unceasing social interactions. Maybe the world has forgotten how much the world has changed since the internet came out, but I haven't forgotten how amazed I would have been in the late 90's if Yahoo, Lycos, AOL, or even Google would have returned search results as relevant as [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=Can%20one%20still%20buy%20a%20new%2C%20top-of-the-range%20film%20camera&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS753US753&oq=Can%20one%20still%20buy%20a%20new%2C%20top-of-the-range%20film%20camera&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i64.854j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

(And for the Exchange members who are clamoring for how off topic this is, I really wanted to leave a long comment or a thread in Meta but neither is possible)

Comment: Ah, the kids these days trope. I personally cannot wait to give my daughter the dilemma of continuing a phone conversation (in the kitchen) vs. getting online.

Comment: Some of us don't have the time or the inclination to spend the sometimes hours worth of research it takes to find an answer to a question. You may have found an answer to this question right off the bat as you claim or it could have taken a while to find an answer. Hence why I'm asking people here. For the record I've googled many photography related questions recently and have had to spend an inordinate amount of time finding an answer.

Kids have inherited a peaceful world? With all these wars in the middle east? I don't think so. Compared to 25 plus years ago I think I had it much better.

Comment: @Corey "When I was your age, we had 3 people yelling to get off the phone because we weren't rich enough for that new call waiting"

Comment: @RichardGray Maybe you really should start learning to learning to do basic research. Some questions are **hard** to find good answers, and that's what this network is for. And yes, undoubtedly the kids kids have inherited a peaceful world. Even with "the middle east" as your single data point, that region has seen conflict for millennia and this decade isn't worse than the last century (world wars, civil wars, western meddling...)

Comment: @RichardGray - not every question is going to get up voted. That being said, the purpose of SE is to provide utility to future readers in addition to helping you, now. Speculative topics like, *will film be around in...* are generally too broad for this type of site. But, it is important to frame questions in a way that provides that future utility, if at all possible.

Comment: @AthomSfere - answering the phone used to be a gamble - it could be your friends, or it could be grandma looking for help in printing out a recipe from her email (chain). Thank you caller ID, for saving me.

Comment: @AthomSfere - Kids have undoubtedly inherited a peaceful world? And you're telling me I'm the one who needs to learn to do basic research? Oh the irony!

Try telling that to the children of Syria, Libya, Yemen, Iraq. Kids who are probably having hot white phosphorus dropped on them as I type this.

The world is **not** undoubtedly peaceful. It largely depends on what country you were born into. To say it is undoubtedly peaceful demonstrates your complete ignorance.

Also, I have many data points. I'm just not going to waste them here.

Comment: @RichardGray "unprecedentedly peaceful world", not that any (or every) spot is at peace. But as a whole, the planet has not seen this level of peace, ever.

Comment: @AthomSfere - That's an entirely subjective opinion, and one I completely disagree with, given the current geopolitical events unfolding today.

Comment: @RichardGray I suppose that's your prerogative. Ignoring a world of objective data and statistics because that's how you feel....?

Comment: @AthomStere - I don't ignore data or statistics. I don't hold beliefs or views because I "feel" that way inclined. I just examine evidence and research.

To say that kids today have **undoubtedly** inherited a peaceful world and then say I need to do research isn't just ridiculous, it's stupid.

Sorry.